# Count Points in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to make a simple Dice Game in JS but I'm stuck at the counting section.

I need to roll the dice, and count them like in Poker (pair, double pair, brelan, flush, etc.).

It's a 2-players game. Here's my code:

```
    var boulier = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    var done = false;

    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        tabWinner[i] = number;
        document.getElementById("p1_de_"+i).src = "de_" + number + ".jpg";
        if (i == 5)
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }
```

It simply get 5 random number between 1 and 6 and it display the linked image.

I need to count points like in poker but I don't know how I can compare multiple array items...

If someone can help me couting those points, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a hand (tabWinner?) - array of numbers

```
var hand = [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]
```

You'd like to sort it first, because everything is much easier with sorted array

```
hand.sort()
```

Then you check for specific combinations starting from big ones

```
// five of a kind
hand[0] == hand[4]

// straight (dunno, there may be a shorter way)
hand[4] - 1 == hand[3] && hand[3] - 1 == hand[2] && hand[2] - 1 == hand[1] && hand[1] - 1 == hand[0]

// four of a kind
hand[0] == hand[3] || hand[1] == hand[4]

// full house
hand[0] == hand[1] && hand[3] == hand[4] && (hand[2] == hand[1] || hand[2] == hand[3])

// and so on
```

Assign points on the way, etc.